# C# ERROR CS7036 Entity Framework and stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, crud

I am trying to do a crud with Entity Framework and stored procedures in SQL Server, I have difficulties with the save method and the modify method.

I get the following error when I try to assign my stored procedure a data model to modify,

> CS7036 C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of

This is my model in Entity Framework:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC97m.png)

This is my data model

```
namespace TiendaStoredProceduresEF.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class RegistroAlmacen
    {
        public decimal IdRegistro { get; set; }
        public decimal IdSucursal { get; set; }
        public decimal IdProducto { get; set; }
        public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }

        public virtual Producto Producto { get; set; }
        public virtual Sucursal Sucursal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the access to the stored procedures in SQL Server:

```
namespace TiendaStoredProceduresEF.Datos
{
    public class RegistroAlmacenAdmin
    {       
        public void GuardarRegistro(RegistroAlmacen modelo)
        {    
            using (TiendaRealEntities contexto = new TiendaRealEntities())
            {
                contexto.GuardarRegistroAlmacen(modelo); 
                contexto.SaveChanges();
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

The error appears on the line

```
contexto.GuardarRegistroAlmacen(modelo);
```

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter IProducto of TiendaRealEntities.GuardarRegistroAlmacen

According to the law on error CS7036, I have to create an empty constructor, but I don't know how or where

Comment: Well, it seems that your method `GuardarRegistroAlmacen` requires a parameter of a type that implements the `IProducto` interface - but the type you are trying to pass in right now - `RegistroAlmacen` - does not implement `IProducto`.....

Comment: not because in my data model that calls model all those variables are contained in "modelo", the problem is that the "modelo" is not initialized or does not have a constructor and I don't know how to put it, on this line  contexto.GuardarRegistroAlmacen(modelo);